# How to create reference in Model Schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

If I have model Products:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 20,
    required: true
},
  description: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 300
  },
  price: Number,
  active: Boolean,
  category: {

  }
});
```

And I must create category, type ObjectID with reference to category model
I create right now this:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 300
},
  description: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 300
  }
});
```

Can someone what to do now? Because i do not know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category object in the schema should be as following:

```
category: { 
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  ref: 'Category' //category model name
}
```

For more information about references you should read the following paragraph:

DBRefs are references from one document to another using the value of the first document’s _id field, collection name, and, optionally, its database name. By including these names, DBRefs allow documents located in multiple collections to be more easily linked with documents from a single collection.
To resolve DBRefs, your application must perform additional queries to return the referenced documents like population queries.

Comment: Can you put some explanation about the these DBRefs ? OP does not seem to have much experience so it would help him understanding this answer better

Comment: Thanks, can u look here and tell me that is okay or no?:)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b18f10fba09afd0db858f534a57f17f8

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Thanks for you feedback, i added some explanation.